# allauth issue: providers list is empty in admin

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've setup allauth according to the readme. syncdb'ed etc.

However when i try to setup a social app in admin the Provider dropdown is empty.

I've tried to print get_list() in the providers/**init**.py file (which I assume is the method being used by models.py & the as_choices() method.

Do you have any pointers as to where I'm doing wrong? :)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

pete

my settings file(well most of it):

```
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)
sys.path.append(SITE_ROOT)
sys.path.append(normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'apps')))
sys.path.append(normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'libs')))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #Authentication/signup backend
    'project.apps.allauth',
    'project.apps.allauth.account',
    'project.apps.allauth.socialaccount',
    'project.apps.allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'django.contrib.admin',

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'project.apps.allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'project.apps.allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.apps.allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 8
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = False
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {'facebook': {'SCOPE': ['email'], 'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type':     'reauthenticate'}, 'METHOD': 'js_sdk', 'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable'}}
```

my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   #(r'^/$', include('project.apps.main.urls')),
                   #(r'^account/$', include('project.apps.account.urls')),
                   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   (r'^registration/', include('project.apps.allauth.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but you appear to be running with a manually tweaked Python path: you placed allauth below project.apps. This may introduce weirdness, for example, think about what happens when allauth starts importing itself: "from allauth import ...". In your case, the same module/code is reachable via project.apps and via allauth directly. Please try "normalizing" your installation, preferably using a tool like virtualenv.

Comment: I must admit I ended up using facebooks javascript SDK instead. Its simpler and possibly more robust. However I think your right with the paths. On another note this seems to be a general issue with Django... the portability of apps if your setup in regards to folders etc. aren't 100 % as prescribed in the docs.